# How to setup php-watson-api-bridge to connect to Watson conversation API?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, watson-conversation

Using the [php-watson-api-bridge](https://github.com/findbrok/php-watson-api-bridge), I am trying to connect with the [Watson Conversation API](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/conversation-v1) to no avail (**Getting 400 error**).

I understand this question might be more useful directing it as issue to the repo as regard this so I did already.

Even though I managed to make a successful call to the API directly using Guzzle. I will appreciate if anyone has a (proven) way to use this bridge.

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
$carpenter = app()->make(Carpenter::class);
$bridge = $carpenter->constructBridge('default', 'conversation');

$response = $bridge->get('https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces', ['auth' => [
            env('WATSON_API_USERNAME'), env('WATSON_API_PASSWORD')
]]);
```

> PS: If there is a need for more explanations, I am ready to provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try ending the URI with a slash and including version date.